# ros node memory usage

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ros

I would like to monitor and log the memory usage of processes being carried out by the different nodes in my ros-based system.

Ideally, the information would be similar to the output of the linux `top` command, but only for ros processes. The `rqt_top` plugin seems promising, but I am unclear about how to use/store information from this package.

Examples/tutorials for `rqt_top` or alternative ways to store memory usage data would be appreciated!

Using ros indigo and Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer!

Jeet Sukumaran's Syrupy (https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/Syrupy) seems to solve my problem quite well and can be easily added to the launch of my ros nodes.